# unusual result from joining two Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables:

first name A

| id | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 |
| 3 | 789 |

second name B:

| id | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

I need join tables A and B with result:

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 4 |
| 2 | 456 |  |
| 3 | 789 | 5 |
| 3 |  | 6 |

Of course instead of x and y columns I have a lot of columns and tables have a lot of rows, so the solution cannot be use"left join" and remove one value.

I've no idea how to get that result in python. Could You help me ?

Comment: Please also add the thing you tried. Question says "left join" can not be the answer, do you know about other join types? Maybe a "full outer join" can help you here.

Comment: I know a lot of types of join. The problem is in the last row, where id is double in table B. After join tables A i B I need show values from table A only once but from B all.